# Custom button in Admin Form

Tags: magento-1.7, adminhtml, forms

I need to add a button in my custom module admin form , which calls an action 'upload'

How can I achieve it ?

Comment: Can you give more details on what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I have made a custom module which needs Multiple images to be uploaded for each item , I want to add Upload Images button on my form , so that I can save images before form submit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When defining a form element you have the option of specifying `after_element_html`. what you put there will be shown after the element itself. Here is an example:

```
$fieldset->addField('some_field', 'text', array(
    'label' => Mage::helper('core')->__('Some label'),
    'name'  => 'some_name',
    'after_element_html' => '<button type="button" onclick="alert(\'Stop clicking me!!\')">Do not click</button>' 
));
```

I think you can start from here. you can use the `onclick` on the button to do an ajax call (or something like that) and upload your image.

Comment: very cool! never knew this

Comment: if you do not want to display text field, then you can use type 'note' instead of 'text'

Answer (score 1):

For system=>configuration:

In your system.xml you can add Form-Elements.
There are 3 relevant nodes:

- frontend_type - corresponding to /lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element
- source_model
- backend_model

I know that you can build your own source- and so I believe backend_model.
It is relative easy to do it. Just add the classpath to your nodevalue like "adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno".

If you have a look to /lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element, you can see File.php which you can use to build the Upload-Frontendtype.

For other admin-sections:

You can use extend Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form and Hmx_Incopay_Block_Widget_Container

In your widget form you can add the following in the constructor:

```
$form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
                                    'id' => 'edit_form',
                                    'action' => $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', array(
                                            'id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')
                                    )),
                                    'method' => 'post',
                                    'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
                                 )
    );
```

and

```
$fieldset->addField(Mage::getStoreConfig('XXXX/input_file_name'), 'file', array(
            'name' => Mage::getStoreConfig('XXXX/input_file_name'),
            'label' => __('CSV account data'),
            'class' => 'required-entry',
            'required' => true,
    ));
```

Dont change the form-id and beware of some other conventions listed here http://blog.kervinramen.com/2012/10/how-magento-widget-form-container.html

Comment: New Url: http://blog.ramen.mu/2012/10/how-magento-widget-form-container.html